# Pull from git before applying org-capture?

Tags: magit, git, org-capture

I'm using org-capture to take project-specific notes by having a notes file in each of several git repositories.  Looking forward, however, I can see danger here: if I'm working on project (1) and I think to drop a note in project (2), I'll probably forget to commit it; doing this on multiple computers and syncing via github just *begs* for merge conflicts.

Does anyone know a way to solve at least part of this problem by having org-capture automatically pull from remote before it starts a note?  I thought of trying to just use advice to do it, but there's no obvious way to do that given that the specific repository isn't selected until after org-capture is run...

Comment: The target in the capture template can be a function called with no argument.  Make that function do the pull as a side-effect?

Comment: Oooh that's a potential idea.  Thank you.  I didn't know you could call a function in the capture template.

Comment: `C-h v org-capture-templates` is helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `defadvice`. This is kind of hook that can get triggered in many situation.

```
(defadvice  next-line (before nextline-before activate)
  (message "Are you using next line?"))
```

For more
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AdvisingFunctions